# App is crashing when I convert string to int

Tags: java, android, string

I use two dimensional array and suppose I want to convert a string to int in a specific element
like that `arr[0][1]="12";`. I am using this

```
int id=0; String[][] description=new String[obj.length][]; 
String[] temp; 
for(int i=0; i<obj.length; i++) { 
   da[i]=obj[i].toString(); temp=da[i].split(","); 
   description[i]=new String[temp.length]; 
   for(int j=0; j<temp.length; j++) {
        // id=new String[temp.length]; 
      description[i][j]=temp[j];
      if(j==0) { 
      try { 
          id=Integer.parseInt(description[i][j]); 
      } 
      catch(NumberFormatException nfe) { // Log exception. } 
      //id=Integer.parseInt(description[i][j].toString());
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   } 
}
```

But it gives null pointer exception.

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Comment: Which line throws the null pointer exception?

Comment: this one id=Integer.parseInt(description[i][j]);

Comment: i think you missing "da" string array initialization.

Comment: i declare in my code like String[] da=new String[obj.length];

Comment: Please add your input object's string representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if its not null then cast to integer:

```
    try { 
             if(description[i][j]!=null && description[i][j].length()>0){
              id=Integer.parseInt(description[i][j]); 
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
          }
```

instead of

```
try { 
          id=Integer.parseInt(description[i][j]); 
      }
```

i hope its work but **description[i][j] must  returns string**.

if id getting value then print toast.otherwise no toast print..

Comment: then which line exception and wht will get exception?after put my code

Comment: Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();